# Nice way of making custom before/after for groups of tests

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I'm writing some tests for an ember project, and I'm looking for a nice way to group certain tests so they can share the same setup/teardown methods.

From what I can tell, it can be done in this way:

```
moduleFor('adapter:application', 'Unit | Adapter | application', {});
test('Test using first moduleFor, which has no before/after', ...);

moduleFor('adapter:application', 'Unit | Adapter | application', {
  beforeEach() {...},
  afterEach() {...}
});
test('Test using new beforeEach/afterEach', ...);
```

However I'm thinking that it will be difficult to figure out which before/after applies to tests, without actually nesting the tests within the `moduleFor` which doesn't appear to be possible with Ember's custom module functions.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I might implement this more cleanly?

Comment: make your `beforeEach` and `afterEach` generic enough that every test can use them and aren't negatively affected by them and put one-offs inside the test themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm totally going to be that guy and suggest using [ember-cli-mocha](https://github.com/switchfly/ember-cli-mocha) since this style testing is done VERY well in it. We use it in all of our projects.

[Example of an acceptance test](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select/blob/master/tests/acceptance/x-select-single-test.js)

[Example of a integration/unit test](https://github.com/thefrontside/ember-impagination/blob/master/tests/integration/components/impagination-dataset-test.js)

If you need to use qunit I know there's a way to do it, but I've only done it once and I don't think I did it correctly. :/

Comment: This looks pretty cool, definitely looks a lot better organized